# Display HUD for moment then return to tableViewController iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to display a brief message as a UIView to the user saying that a link has been copied to the clipboard. I am able to copy the String to the clipboard and I am able to get the image to display, however when the animation has completed I want to return to the tableViewController I copied the link from. Currently I am able to dismiss the tableViewController that I copy the link from.

I copied a lot of the code from the 3rd Ray Wenderlich iOS Apprentice tutorial. The main difference from their implementation and mine is that they simply dismiss the current TableViewController returning to the ViewController. I have tried removeFromSuperview(), which might be on the right track but then I don't know how to return to the tableView(there is just a blank screen).

I tried to present the tableViewController again but that makes no sense since it is already being displayed.

My UIView takes up the whole screen for a reason it needs to so the user can't interrupt the animation but by doing that I can't return to the

My question is how do you "dismiss" a UIView and return user interaction back to the tableView below it?

I'm not trying to use a UIAlertController either just a quick message in the form of a UIView.

Code is below:

**BrandDetailViewController**

```
func hud() {
    let hudView = HUDView.hud(inView: navigationController!.view, animated: true)
    hudView.text = "Copied"
    //hudView.tag = 222
    afterDelay(0.8) {
        //self.present(self, animated: true, completion: nil)
        //hudView.popToViewController(animated: true, completion: nil)
        //navigationController!.view.pushViewController(self, animated: true)
        //1. self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        //2. self.view.willRemoveSubview(hudView)
        //3. self.tableView.reloadData()
        //4. hudView.viewWithTag(222) as! UIView
        hudView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        hudView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: hudView)
        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}

func afterDelay(_ seconds: Double, closure: @escaping () -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds, execute: closure)
}
```

**HUDView**

```
class HUDView: UIView {
    var text = ""

    class func hud(inView view: UIView, animated: Bool) -> HUDView {
        let hudView = HUDView(frame: view.bounds)
        hudView.isOpaque = false

        view.addSubview(hudView)
        hudView.show(animated: animated)
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        return hudView
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        ....
    }

    func show(animated: Bool) {
        if animated {
            alpha = 0
            transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: [], animations: {
                self.alpha = 1
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the hud is always the same `size` as the `view` it's being presented in there is no need to block the `userInteraction`. Try removing all the `isUserInteractionEnabled` code.

Comment: Also why are you presenting the `hud` on the `NavigationViewController` view? `navigationController!.view`.

Comment: I just started messing with presenting the hud on self.view. The issue with that is the checkmark doesn't get drawn. Not sure why. To Answer your Q though, the example I was following did the same.

Comment: Did removing that code do anything?

Comment: This line is also doing nothing `self.view.sendSubview(toBack: hudView)` since the `hudView` is being presented on the `navigation.view`.

Comment: YES!!! Thanks. I was just cleaning up after my many experiments. I kept navigationController!.view and removed the interaction = false in the class fun hud in HUDView(as you suggested). This worked